# changing position of a vector elements according to other vector elements position

Tags: matlab

I have two row vectors such as

```
a=[1 8 3 6 9];
b=[2 1 4 3 6];
```

now I want to organize elements of `a` vector in descending orders and change the position of `b` vector according to new 'a' vector elements position.

```
a_new=[9 8 6 3 1];
b_new=[6 1 3 4 2];
```

Is it possible in Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html). You specifically want to take the second output argument from that and use it to reorder `b`:

```
a=[1 8 3 6 9]; 
b=[2 1 4 3 6];

[a_new, b_ind]=sort(a,'descend'); 

b_new=b(b_ind);
```

Comment: @subahamahmuda If this has resolved this issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).